# @Classmethods vs Defs in django

Tags: python, ajax, database, django

I'm building an ajax page that submits some data. When a submit button is clicked, I wish to get the data with request.GET. But what I do with the data is based on actions, i.e. "submit", "change", "delete", which is also gotten from the request.GET.

I'm trying to figure out the best approach add/modify/delete within my database as my models contain foreign keys to other models.

Should I do this:

```
# Model4
class Model4(models.Model):
    .... data ...

# Model3
class Model3(models.Model):
    .... data ....

# Model2
class Model2(models.Model):
    ... data ...
    foreign key to Model3 & Model4

# Model1
class DataModel(models.Model):
    # ----- Model data -----
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    data = models.ForeignKey(Model2, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


    @classmethod
    def submit():
        pass
    @classmethod
    def change():
        pass
    @classmethod
    def delete():
        pass
```

This model links to the Model2 that has two foreign keys to two other models, Model3 & Model4

Or should I do something like this

```
# methods within the views.py
def submit( DataModel Object, ... data ... ):
    # create new data objects and associate with DataModel
    pass
def change( DataModel Object, ... data ... ):
    # change data object associated with DataModel
    pass
def delete( DataModel Object, ... data ... ):
    # delete data object associated with DataModel
    pass
```

Or should I be doing something completely different?
Here is what the submit looks like:

```
def submitdata(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('loginregistration.views.login'))

    results = {'success':False, 'message':"invalid request"}
    if request.method == u'GET':
        GET = request.GET
        if GET.has_key(u'datamodel_id') and GET.has_key(u'action') and GET.has_key(u'data'):

            datamodel_id = GET[u'datamodel_id']
            action = GET[u'action']


            data_model = DataModel.objects.get(datamodel_id=datamodel_id)
            if action == u"submit":
                results = data_model.submit() # or submit(datamodel_id, data)
            elif action == u"change":
                results = data_model.change() # or change(datamodel_id, data)
            elif action == u"delete":
                results = data_model.delete() # or delete(datamodel_id, data)
            else:
                results = False

    json = simplejson.dumps(results)
    return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: Fat Models, Helper Modules, Thin Views, Stupid Templates